Proving that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a group without using equivalence relations
I am self-studying a set of lecture notes on group theory, and it gives a definition of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ without equivalence relations. It defines it as the set $[0,1)$ with "addition mod $1$," i.e.,
$$
x \oplus y := \begin{cases}
x + y & \text{ if $x + y < 1$} \\
x + y - 1 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
I am trying to prove that this operation turns $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ into a group, but am having some trouble. My attempt is below.

Well-defined
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer that is less than or equal to $x$. So $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x < \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ and therefore $0 \leq x - \lfloor x \rfloor < 1$. By uniqueness of the floor function, the map sending $x \mapsto x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is well-defined.
Associativity.
This is the property I'm least certain on, but it seems to rely on properties of the floor function. What I want to show is:

\begin{align*}
(x \oplus y) \oplus z &= x \oplus (y \oplus z) \\ 
((x+y)-\lfloor x + y \rfloor) \oplus z &= x \oplus ((y+z) - \lfloor y + z \rfloor) \\
(((x+y)-\lfloor x + y \rfloor) - \lfloor (x+y)-\lfloor x + y \rfloor + z\rfloor &= (x +((y+z) - \lfloor y + z \rfloor) - (\lfloor x + ((y+z) - \lfloor y + z \rfloor \rfloor. 
\end{align*}

I know that $\lfloor a + n \rfloor = \lfloor a \rfloor$ for any integer $n$, and the floor function always gives an integer, so I can drop any "floor functions without a floor function". That makes my 'want to show' statement:

\begin{align*}
((x+y) - \lfloor x + y \rfloor) - \lfloor x+y-z \rfloor &= (x+y+z - \lfloor y + z \rfloor) - \lfloor x + y + z \rfloor \\
x + y - \lfloor x + y \rfloor = \lfloor x + y + z \rfloor &=  (x+y+z - \lfloor y + z \rfloor) - \lfloor x + y + z \rfloor.
\end{align*}

And then I'm stuck. An alternative (and much simpler approch) would be to say that in the real numbers, $(x+y)+z = x + (y+z)$. So by uniqueness of the floor function, I can apply this construction iteratively to deduce this above statement.
Identity
This is the only property that seems more or less clear to me. If $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, then $x \in [0,1)$, so $x \oplus 0 = x \oplus 0 = x \in [0,1)$.
Inverses
I'm not completely certain on this. If $x + y < 1$, then surely $x$ and $y$ are not inverses, so if I want an inverse for $x$, I definitely need to look in the case where $x + y \geq 1$. It seems that subtracting $x$ from $1$ will do the trick. So given $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, take $y = 1 - x$. As $0 \leq x < 1$, it follows that $0 < 1 - x \leq 1$, so by gluing $0$ and $1$ together, we get $y \in [0,1)$. Then $x + y = 1$, so $x \oplus y = x + y - 1 = 0$.

I greatly appreciate any feedback. I am most concerned with whether my argument for well-definedness works and how I can show associativity.

You could use a direct approach, without using the floor function. Did you try?
Moreover, you say "If $x+y<1$, then surely $x$ and $y$ are not inverses", this is not right, because we are not interested in this, what you said after that is right, the point is exactly that one :)

It's not a good idea to start an argument with the conclusion that you are trying to reach. For instance, when you want to prove associativity, you should not begin with the equation that expresses associativity!

We define $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as $[0,1)$ with the following operation:
$$
x \oplus y := \begin{cases}
x + y & \text{if $x + y < 1$}, \\
x + y - 1 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
for any $x, y \in [0,1)$. How does this operation work? Essentially, it takes two real numbers in $[0,1)$ and applies the standard sum in $\mathbb{R}$. If the result falls in $[0,1)$, it is left unchanged; otherwise, we adjust it by subtracting $1$ to bring it back into $[0,1)$. It is intuitive to think that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ forms a group. We now show that it is indeed a group (and actually abelian as well).

Associativity
We need to prove that for any $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $(x \oplus y) \oplus z = x \oplus (y \oplus z)$.
Let us start with the first member:
$$
(x \oplus y) \oplus z = \begin{cases}
(x + y) \oplus z & \text{if $x + y < 1$}, \\
(x + y - 1) \oplus z & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Expanding this further:
$$
= \begin{cases}
x + y + z & \text{if $x + y + z < 1$}, \\
x + y + z - 1 & \text{if $x + y < 1$ and $x + y + z \geq 1$}, \\
x + y + z - 1 & \text{if $x + y \geq 1$ and $x + y + z < 2$}, \\
x + y + z - 2 & \text{if $x + y \geq 1$ and $x + y + z \geq 2$}.
\end{cases}
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
= \begin{cases}
x + y + z & \text{if $x + y + z < 1$}, \\
x + y + z - 1 & \text{if $1 \leq x + y + z < 2$}, \\
x + y + z - 2 & \text{if $x + y + z \geq 2$}.
\end{cases}
$$

For the second member, observe that it produces the same result since $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is an abelian group and the roles of $x$ and $z$ are symmetric. Explicitly:
$$
x \oplus (y \oplus z) = \begin{cases}
x \oplus (y + z) & \text{if $y + z < 1$}, \\
x \oplus (y + z - 1) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Expanding this:
$$
= \begin{cases}
x + y + z & \text{if $x + y + z < 1$}, \\
x + y + z - 1 & \text{if $y + z < 1$ and $x + y + z \geq 1$}, \\
x + y + z - 1 & \text{if $y + z \geq 1$ and $x + y + z < 2$}, \\
x + y + z - 2 & \text{if $x + y + z \geq 2$}.
\end{cases}
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
= \begin{cases}
x + y + z & \text{if $x + y + z < 1$}, \\
x + y + z - 1 & \text{if $1 \leq x + y + z < 2$}, \\
x + y + z - 2 & \text{if $x + y + z \geq 2$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, $(x \oplus y) \oplus z = x \oplus (y \oplus z)$.

Identity
The number $0$ serves as the identity element in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. For any $x \in [0,1)$, we have $x \oplus 0 = 0 \oplus x = x$ because $x + 0 = x < 1$.

Inverse
For any $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, there exists $y_x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \oplus y = y \oplus x = 0$.
Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, so $x \in [0,1)$. Let $y_x = 1 - x$. Then:
$$
x \oplus y = x + (1 - x) = 0,
$$
since $x + y = 1$, so $x \oplus y = x + y - 1$. Similarly, $y \oplus x = 0$, which shows that $x \oplus y = y \oplus x = 0$.


This proves that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a group.
Moreover, it is also abelian, meaning $x \oplus y = y \oplus x$ for any $x, y \in [0,1)$.
